# Angular Material 6 grid list align-items and justify-content to flex-start

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use Angular Material 6 Dynamic grid-list. The example relating to the documentation puts contents of the grid in the centre of each tile. See example [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/voqveyovkjx?file=app%2Fgrid-list-dynamic-example.ts)

I want the content to go in the top left hand corner of each tile.

I have tried the following css which does not work.

```
.mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqk8tr?file=styles.css

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put in `styles.css`:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dn7nqs)

```
.mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {
   justify-content: flex-start !important ;
   align-items: flex-start !important;
}
```

Comment: is there a way that it doesn't have to be in the style.css?

Comment: You can use `/deep/ .mat-grid-tile .mat-figure` but that is going to be deprecated, or you can use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your Component decorator. You can also use `unset` and add another class to your mat-grid-tile instead of the `!important` in case you ever want to cascade further.

Comment: using `!important` is not a good practice https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/declaration-no-important. U can wrap your item(s) inside a div and give it a CSS width of 100%

Comment: I have to agree with @MorloMbakop, it's not good practice, and there are real life experiences that back up why this is when adding !important to a shared component. If, however, this component is small (and will always be small) and local (i.e. will never be used in any other component), this gets the job done. You definitely should remove `!important` the moment you add more to this component or decide to use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

This might not fit everyone's needs, but instead of wrestling with the functionality and css properties in order to fit alignment, your component can set the width/height of inner components to 100%. This way, Angular will still get its way (center it all!), and you can adjust the alignment as you see fit (left, right).

Example here with simple checkboxes (my real world scenario), but you can obviously expand on this with whatever your situation is (most complex example is the last one).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74i5kw

Comment: Thanks understood that I need to use div for <li>

Answer (score 3):

Although this is late, I was having the same issue. I had to use the !important variant to achieve what was needed. Then I got to my component's CSS and added:

```
:host >>> .mat-figure{
  align-items: start !important;
}
```

More information - https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
:ng-deep .mat-grid-tile-content{
    justify-content: flex-start !important ;
    align-items: flex-start !important;
 }
```

Comment: It seems really near to the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

add the following style to the content of the grid-tile : `"align-self: start"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
::ng-deep .mat-grid-tile-content{
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?