# How to make styles.css in Angular not affect every element with that selector?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I can align the content of my grid tiles but I only ever wanted it to affect the table that was inside of a grid.

I have this:

```
.mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {
   justify-content: flex-start !important ;
   align-items: flex-start !important;
}
```

EDIT: This piece of css above came from this previous solutution:
[Angular Material 6 grid list align-items and justify-content to flex-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51920250/angular-material-6-grid-list-align-items-and-justify-content-to-flex-start/51920350)

in `styles.css` but obviously it affects everything that's inside of a tile but I only want it to affect my `mat-table`. Is there a way to make this not be the case?

```
<mat-grid-list id="parentGrid" cols="4" rowHeight="100px">
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </mat-grid-tile>


    <mat-grid-tile id="table" colspan="3" rowspan="6">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="someArray">
            <!--- removed for space -->
        </table>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
```

I'll have everything aligned to the top left but I just want my table to be in the top left and have tried doing `#table` and in the table's tile I would have `id="table"` but this wouldn't work.

Comment: What is the element corresponding to `.mat-figure`? I don't see it in your template, so why is it in your css?

Comment: I couldn't quite figure this out either, it was in the solution link I edited in above  when I previously couldn't align any grid elements to a position I wanted.

Comment: what do you mean you couldn't figure it out. You wrote that line of code, right?

Comment: I did, it was in solution link but there was no reason why it was written and I can't find anything on it. ```mat-grid-tile``` makes sense of course but I couldn't find the reason for why that ```.mat-figure``` was included in that link solution but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing the CSS rule given by you with the below one:

```
.mat-grid-tile > table {
   justify-content: flex-start !important ;
   align-items: flex-start !important;
}
```