# How to disable flex from Angular mat-grid-list

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Html

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
    <mat-tab label="New Registration" > 

        <ul *ngFor="let item of fakedata; index as i; ">           
                    <mat-card style="border-radius: 10px; margin-left: 5%; margin-top: 1%; margin-right: 5%;">
                        <mat-grid-list cols="3">
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                               <p>sometext</p><br>
                               <p>sometext</p><br>
                               <p>sometext</p><br>
                               <p>sometext</p>
                        </mat-grid-tile>
                        <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
                        <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
                    </mat-grid-list>
                    </mat-card>     
        </ul>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="  other content">  other content </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label=" other content"> yet other content</mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

Use this CSS

```
.mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block !important ;
    align-items: flex-start; 
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also tried answer from here [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51920250/angular-material-6-grid-list-align-items-and-justify-content-to-flex-start/51920350)
I tried above css with Viewencapsulation ON/OFF
Also tried clearing browser cache
When I disable flex property it display correct output
[image: When I disable flex property it display correct output]
What I am doing wrong?
Angular-9
Browser - Chrome

Thankyou

Comment: If you want to get rid of display:flex, just apply display:block for instance of your .mat-grid-tile .mat-figure

Comment: @PIIANTOM I also tried ```display:block``` still not working

Comment: Use ViewEncapsulation.None and in the css display: block!important; . Try both things together

Comment: If you've figured out the answer to your question, then post how you've fixed it as an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution
Disable encapsulation

```
import { Component, OnInit , ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None //Add this line
})
```

And In component.css

```
.mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block !important ;
    align-items: flex-start; 
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In /layout-grid.component.css add this:

```
::ng-deep md-grid-tile.mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {
  display: block !important; /* or whichever you need */
}
```

This will override the one in angular material css.

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: No change i updated problem with stackbliz link